# How to restrict textbox in html to only accept letters with space?

Tags: html, pattern-matching, input-type-file

I want to restrict textbox to only accept letters with spaces.
I have tried this but it is not accepting spaces

```
<input type="text" 
       maxlength = "15"  
       name="txtName" 
       pattern="[A-Za-z \s*]"  
       class="form-control"  
       placeholder="Name" 
       required="required" 
       class="validate">
```

I also try this pattern.

```
pattern="[A-Za-z][" "]"
```

I don't want to use any function for this pattern in my code.
How can I do this in simple one line code.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the anchors and quantifiers:

```
pattern="^[A-Za-z \s*]+$"
```

here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwd8tey2/).